# Modify jQuery validation message within the function itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers, validation

I'd like to know if it's possible to modify the message of a validation:

```
var message = "default"
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myOwnValidation", function(value, element, param) {
    if(param == "something"){
        message = "Hi";
        return true;
    }
    else{
        message = "Bye";
        return false;
    }
}, message);
```

As in Javascript there are no pointers I know that var *message* will be loaded at the beginning so it will be *default*.

There is any way to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass an object containing that message instead, then work with this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addMethod` can take a function as the message argument, where you can return the custom message like

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("test", function (value, element, param) {
    //some rules
    return this.optional(element) || value == param;
}, function (param, element) {
    if (param == 'myfield') {
        return 'message1'
    } else if (param == 'myfield2') {
        return 'message2'
    } else {
        return 'default'
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nLMBQ/)

Comment: Thank you!!!
A function as a message was the point. I'll write my code just in case anyone can use it

Answer (score 0):

With Arun idea, setting a function as a message I did this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "myOwnValidation", 
    function(value, element, param) {//Validation
        if(param == "something"){
            this.message = "Hi";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            this.message = "Bye";
            return false;
        }
    }, 
    function(){//Message
        var messageAux = this.message;
        delete this.message;
        return messageAux;
    }
);
```

I save a message inside parent function, then it is accesible in message function, I save it in an auxiliary variable and delete from the parent function, and finally return it.

Improvements are welcome.